# Jenkinsfile OR condition for nodes?

Tags: jenkins, docker-compose, jenkins-pipeline

I am in a situation where I use docker-compose to build some local environments for testing. Docker compose has a drawback of only being able to have subnets in the range 172.16 to 172.31 and then over to 192.168 range. But unfortunately the 192.168 range is the IP range in our intranet. To cut the story short, I soon run out of networks in docker-compose. To overcome this I want to add another machine as a build node and have some sort of balancing act where I can specify an optional node in Jenkinsfile and the docker-compose clusters are deployed in a load balanced fashion. Is that doable in Jenkins land?

Comment: I‘m not quite sure what you want to do. If you add another node how would it not consume an IP address? Load balancing in Jenkins works using labels. But I assume you’re talking about something else?

Comment: So the issue is one of the buildservers runs out of networks for docker-compose. So I would be adding another buildserver and want some way of scheduling the builds on this new server where in networks can be created. So sort of like an option of builds to run on either Node A or Node B thus reducing the chances of just one node running out of networks.

Comment: By build servers you mean the servers hosting your docker containers?

Comment: Yes, thats what I mean.